# List Git branch currently on each EC2

Tags: github, aws, amazon-ec2

We have a handful of AWS EC2s set up for testing ongoing feature developments.  I'm wondering if anyone knows an easy, automated way to keep track of which git branch we're testing on each EC2.  Maybe with github hooks?

For example, we might be testing with various internal departments:

- a new navigation menu on test1.oursite.com
- new pricing model on test2.oursite.com
- updated branding on test3.oursite.com
- new layout on test4.oursite.com

When I'm looking for an available server to test a new branch, it'd be great to have an accurate list of what's currently on what.  Is this a solved problem?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you deploy the branches to the servers?

Comment: Manually.  With a git checkout / pull.

Comment: maybe the real answer is to automate that